# Use Military-time value as Time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have created a table

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable

(food VARCHAR(20) references myfood(BIN)
,name NUMERIC(2)
,servingsize VARCHAR(15)
,time TIMESTAMP
,PRIMARY KEY(food, time)
);
```

and what I want is to insert data in to this table which I use:

```
INSERT INTO dinnertime (food, name, servingsize, time) VALUES 
('earl', 3, 'one cup', '1300'),
('phebeo', 2, 'two cup', '1100'),
('apollo', 1, 'one Cup', '0700'),
('oscar', 4, 'one cup', '2200');
```

But PostgrSQL does not let me do this. The problem is with the time. What changes do I need to make to my table for it to take this format of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use time instead of timestamp (timestamp is date + time, you only have time), then convert to one of the recognized formats for time:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Thx I was wrong changing to time, works ... postgreSQL recognized my input. Thank you!

Comment: I was gonna but it said, wait 3 min .. i was waiting :D